# Can't get actual size from qss stylized QWidgets

Tags: qt, qt4, size, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I can´t get the real size of the widgets that i stylized with a StyleSheet in QT 4.7 after adding the contents.

For example, i want to get the size so I set an offset to the widget when shown so it is well positioned. Or many other examples.

It just doesn´t work. I always get 0. I tried geometry(), fixedSize()...etc.

How do you do it?

Comment: Is this before or after your widget has been shown?

Comment: Yes. The widget has been shown already.